# Is it necessary for the Sun to be "inside" the parabola in a parabolic orbit?

Tags: orbital-motion

Can the sun be "outside" of the parabola of a parabolic orbit, but its focal point inside? Personally, I don't see a problem with this case, I was just curious and wanted to ask a quick question

Comment: Orbits are elliptical.  An object on a parabolic path goes by the sun one time and never returns.

Comment: @DavidWhite - if the object trajectory tries to go _through_ part of the sun, then part of the sun is outside the orbit. Not good for the object, mind you...

Comment: an answer here has plots of possible orbits, where the center of gravitational field is in a focal point of the conic sections  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/229249/how-are-orbits-made-stable

Comment: @DavidWhite By a parabolic orbit I was meant to say an orbit with an eccentricity of e=1; this is a parabolic trajectory, perhaps I didn't phrase my question correctly

Comment: The only way the focal point can be "outside" the curve is if there is a *repulsive* force between the two objects. That is possible for two electrically charged particles, of course.

Comment: @HiddenEagle1, e=1 corresponds to a parabolic trajectory, which is NOT an orbit.  Such an object passes by a gravitational body one time and continues traveling to infinity, at which point, its velocity and kinetic energy are zero.  Of course, this may be a case of a disagreement on how terms should be defined, but see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_trajectory